# Magento Sort By Entity ID Descending

Tags: php, magento

I am looking to amend the default Magento (1.6) catalog sort to add an option of **sorting by the products entity ID**, and then make this the default sort.

(Searched all over StackOverflow and Google but can only find solutions that are either for older Magento versions or edit core files.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to sort by an attribute which exists because of - and should only be used in the context of - the storage scheme?

Comment: @benmarks, please elaborate, I'm genuinely curious why this would be bad coding. The ID will never change, and sorting by ID descending would always give me the newest products first which is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Responding in an answer below :-)

Comment: Also: should this apply to all contexts, or just to product list block with the toolbar (i.e. category and catalog search pages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-join-filter-select-and-sort-attributes-fields-and-tables/ is a good article which gives information on how you can filter and sort the collection.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about it without changing any core files is to copy the Toolbar.php file located:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

then create a new directory path (if you haven't created one) under:

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

Now replace the following from line 232:

```
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
```

to

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='position'){ //defines the sort option
//sort by entity_id (descending)
$this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc');
} else {
$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
}
}
```

Lastly, reindex and refresh cache on your Magento backend and your ready to go.